# Scala nested arrays flattening

Tags: arrays, scala, collections, flatten

How to flatten an array of nested arrays of any depth ?

For instance

```
val in = Array( 1, Array(2,3), 4, Array(Array(5)) )
```

would be flattened onto

```
val out = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Mixing up values of different types in a collection is in general a bad idea—your `in` could only have type `Array[Any]`, which means you're stuck with some kind of downcasting.

Comment: `Int` and `Array[Int]` _are_ different types, and the only type they have in common is `Any`.

Comment: @TravisBrown True, what could be an approach to a mixed up array ?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, a tree data structure may be more useful here. Then to 'flatten' the tree, you just need to traverse it.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks very much for the insighful comments. Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have mixed `Int` and `Array[Int]`, which is not a very good idea to begin with, you can do something like

```
in.flatMap{ case i: Int => Array(i); case ai: Array[Int] => ai }
```

(it will throw an exception if you've put something else in your array).  You can thus use this as the basis of a recursive function:

```
def flatInt(in: Array[Any]): Array[Int] = in.flatMap{
  case i: Int => Array(i)
  case ai: Array[Int] => ai
  case x: Array[_] => flatInt(x.toArray[Any])
}
```

If you don't know what you've got in your nested arrays, you can replace the above `Int`s by `Any` and get a flat `Array[Any]` as a result.  (Edit: the `Any` case then needs to go last.)

(Note: this is not tail-recursive, so it can overflow the stack if your arrays are nested extremely deeply.)

Comment: Wow—I didn't realize the compiler would do the right (wrong) thing with `case ai: Array[Int] =>`.

Comment: Many Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: @TravisBrown - Arrays are not generic in the JVM.

Comment: @RexKerr: Right—it just looks syntactically so much like something that's about to earn you a warning.